# How to generate sitemap for videos on rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sitemap-generator-gem

I am using `sitemap_generator` for my rails app. I was able to generate sitemap for everything except for video links on the website.  Following is my

**sitemap.rb**

```
Equipment.find_each do |e|
  add search_equipments_path(e), :changefreq => 'weekly'
 end

 Equipment.find_each do |more|
  add equipment_details_path(more), :changefreq => 'weekly'
 end

 Category.find_each do |c|
  add search_equipments_path(:category_id=>c.id), :changefreq => 'weekly'
 end

 Category.find_each do |sub|
  add search_equipments_path(:sub_category=>sub.id), :changefreq => 'weekly'
 end

 Service.find_each do |s|
  add service_details_path(s), :changefreq => 'weekly'
 end

 WantedEquipment.find_each do |f|
  add wanted_equipments_path(f), :changefreq => 'weekly'
 end

 StaticPage.find_each do |t|
  add benefits_for_buyers_path(t), :changefreq => 'weekly'
 end

 StaticPage.find_each do |sel|
  add benefits_for_sellers_path(sel), :changefreq=> 'weekly'
 end

 StaticPage.find_each do |ser|
  add benefits_for_service_providers_path(ser), :changefreq=> 'weekly'
 end

 add '/about-us'
 add '/terms-and-conditions'
 add '/pricing-plans'
 add '/how-it-work'
```

This what is given on the documentation on the gem page for generating video sitemap:

```
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.create do
  add('/index.html', :video => {
    :thumbnail_loc => 'http://www.example.com/video1_thumbnail.png',
    :title => 'Title',
    :description => 'Description',
    :content_loc => 'http://www.example.com/cool_video.mpg',
    :tags => %w[one two three],
    :category => 'Category'
  })
end
```

I am not able to understand how to pass these values dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to generate video contents on basis of `dynamic data`, try this:

```
Model.all.each do |e|
      video = VideoInfo.new(e.video_url)
      add("https://example.com/views/#{e.slug}", :video => {
        :thumbnail_loc => "#{video.thumbnail_medium}",
        :title => "#{video.title}",
        :description => "#{video.description}",
        :content_loc => "#{e.video_url}",
        :tags => e.slug.split('-'),
        :player_loc => video.embed_url  
        })
end
```

Here `VideoInfo` is gem used for getting video meta info.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use this sample but change it to your model name:

```
 SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.create do
  add '/contact_us', 'changefreq': 'weekly'
  Article.find_each do |article|
    add article_path(article), lastmod: article.updated_at
  end
end
```

As you can see he makes find_each on articles model. So you can do the same on your video model.

Comment: That's the problem ,there is no video model. Just a button linking to youtube url. A online sitemap generator is generating a sitemap for that too. I don't know how can I do that using this gem.

Comment: This is what I have `<% if @equipment.Verified? && @equipment.video_url.present? %>
            <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal3">Click here to view video</a>
          <% end %>`

Comment: so why don't you create a video model. Even if its so simple just one field? Generate model at the end you need to get all yours values for that field URL to youtube, and as you see in sample in method add after '/contact_us', 'changefreq': 'weekly' configuration values for each line or each value sitemap generator also need that URL value. I think that you can use also here  db query result like @allurls = somemode.all and doing each trough that.  Do you have urls in db ?

Comment: Yes I have `video_url` column in `Equipment` model.

Comment: So you can then try    Equipment.find_each do |equ|
    add equipment_path(equ.video_url), lastmod: Equipment.video_url.updated_at
  end